# how to download video thumbnail from telegram using pyrogram bot?

Tags: python, telegram, pyrogram

I want to download thumbnail of a video from telegram using `pyrogram`. Previously, I was able to download it by using telethon but now telegram has support of files greater than 2gb , and currently telethon doesn't support files greater than 2gb that is why I can't download thumbnails of file greater than 2gb with telethon, so I am trying to download thumbnails with `pyrogram` but unable to figure it out , so is there anyone that can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is The Code which worked for me

```
async def thumbnail_download(bot, message):
    # Get the Thumbnail Dict
    thumbs=message.video.thumbs[0]
    
    # Get the file_id
    file_id=thumbs.file_id
    
    # Download the Thumbnail
    location=await bot.download_media(file_id)

    # Thumbnail location
    print(location)
```